# first() returns and array instead of stdClass object - Laravel 5.2 MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

When execute below query then it given me array of object instead of stdClass object. I am using  Laravel 5.2 and Mongodb. Please help

```
$student = DB::table('students')->first();
print_r($student);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will u please tell why you need stdClass object

Comment: I am working on existing project so which are using stdClass syntax everywhere i have setup laravel code on my local machine then above query giving array object data .

Comment: `$student`, `$students` Are you sure your variables are correct?

Comment: yes. this is typo .thanks

Comment: Instead of print_r() use dd($student). first() returns object

Comment: doing this it is showing only stdClass object but not working

Comment: thinking that I have missing something at the installation and db migration time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this :

```
$student = DB::table('students')->first(); 
$student = (object)$student;
print_r($student)
```